# Unable to install Firebase for iOS xCode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, firebase

I follow the official video of Google and other videos on youtube but I am not able to install firebase SDK through cocoa-pods. Bundle Identifier and everything is correct. 
Error is :
*### Error

```
JSON::ParserError - 767: unexpected token at ''* 
――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
[!] Oh no, an error occurred.
I have attached my pod file content. 

> # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project platform :ios, '9.0'
> 
>     target 'FirebaseCrash' do
>       # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
>       use_frameworks!
> 
>       # Pods for FirebaseCrash
>     
>      pod 'Firebase/Auth'  
>      pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
>      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos` and upgrade to CocoaPods 1.9.2 to prevent recurrence

Details at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9672